# How to create a Typescript declaration from object to an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have the following object:

`myObj = [ [ x, y, z ], [ k, l ], [ i ] ]`

The values of `x`, `y`, `k` and all others can be any value from this other object:

`options = { A: 'red', B: 'green', C: 'blue' }`

How to declare the type of `myObj`? So I can get this:

```
type MyType = ???
myObj: MyType = [ [ ...
```

Having hard time to figuring this out.

***Appreciate your attention!!!***

Edit:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/blagus/pen/YzajMOP)

Comment: Do you mean x, y, z and so on can take the values `red`, `green` and `blue` ?

Comment: Are all the elements in myObj of type options?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that others can paste into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue for themselves.  Right now I'd have to guess at and re-create `x`, `y`, `z`, etc., just to get to the part where I can start working on it

Comment: _Do you mean x, y, z and so on can take the values red, green and blue ?_

Yes, but furthermore they will only receive the values from `options.A` or `options.B` and so on

_Are all the elements in myObj of type options?_

All elements in myObj will receive the value of any of the options, e.g.: `myObj[1][2] = options.A`

Comment: Codepen: https://codepen.io/blagus/pen/YzajMOP

Answer (score 0):

```
type Color = ('red'|'green'|'blue')
type MyType = [[Color,Color,Color],[Color,Color],[Color]]
const myObj: MyType = [['red','red','red'],['red','red'],['red']]
```

Comment: I am not sure the length of the sub-arrays... so:
`type MyType = Color[][]`
...would be right?

Comment: Also `type Color` does not come from the values on `options`

Comment: please provide an example of myObj. Is `x = { A: 'red', B: 'green', C: 'blue' }`? Or is `x = 'red'`

Comment: Second option, `x = 'red'`

Answer (score 0):

```
type MyType = ('red'|'green'|'blue')[][]
const options = { A: 'red', B: 'green', C: 'blue' };

const myObj: MyType = [
  [
    options.A,
    options.C,
    options.B
  ],
  [ 'red', 'green' ],
  [ options.C ]
];
```

Comment: How can `'red'|'green'|'blue'` be one of the values in `options` ? Should `options` be an enum, and if so, how to make `myObj` be validated by those values?

Comment: @blagus not sure what are you asking for, but edited my answer, you can also check this https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-create-type-from-object-values